# find inode/file using specific block on running xfs filesystem

Tags: filesystems, xfs

I know that block 12024039 is bad on sda1 and I want to find out what file in the xfs filesystem is using that block and is thus corrupt.  How do I do that?  When I run

```
xfs_db -f -c 'blockget -b 12024039' /dev/sda1
```

I get the error

```
ERROR: The filesystem has valuable metadata changes in a log which needs to
be replayed.  Mount the filesystem to replay the log, and unmount it before
re-running xfs_db.  If you are unable to mount the filesystem, then use
the xfs_repair -L option to destroy the log and attempt a repair.
Note that destroying the log may cause corruption -- please attempt a mount
of the filesystem before doing this.
```

Is there anyway to do this without unmounting.  This is something I do all the time with ext4 filesystems.

Comment: Try `-r

Open device or filename read-only. This option is required if the filesystem is mounted.`

Comment: Unfortunately "-r" instead of "-f" (or both) does not work either.  Same result.

Comment: Try `-i -r`. "Allows execution on a mounted filesystem, provided it is mounted read-only". I wanted to test it, but finally a reboot solved my issue.

Comment: I now tried the same on a different machine and nope, I was not able to execute it without unmounting. Sad.